# Router and switch with backup device

Tags: switch, router, home-networking

I have a linksys router and a netgear 24 port switch. Both are gigabit but the switch is much higher quality.

My question is if I have switch connected to a router and then the backup device and computer attached to the switch do the devices communicate to each other through just the switch or both the router and the switch.

Comment: Not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Ask this question on superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

So you have a switch.  Connected to this switch is a computer, a backup device, and a router(for internet access, I presume).

When your computer is talking to your backup device, the traffic flows up your computer's network cable to the switch, through come circuitry in the switch, out the network cable to your backup device. The router doesn't even come into play until you need to reach an outside network.